# What does $E(X = k)$ mean if $X \sim Geom(p)$?

Tags: probability, distributions, conditional-probability, expected-value, geometric-distribution

So, I have the following question for homework assignment:
$X_{1}$, $X_{2}$ have geometric distributions with parameters $p$ and $1-p$ respectively, $X_{1} \sim Geom(p)$, $X_{2} \sim Geom(1-p)$. $X_{1}$, $X_{2}$ are random independent variables. Find the distribution of ${P(X_{1} = k \mid X_{1} + X_{2} = n)}$ and the expected value $E(X_{1} = k \mid X_{1} + X_{2} = n)$. Now I understand how to calculate ${P(X_{1} = k \mid X_{1} + X_{2} = n)}$ but I don't even know how to interpret $E(X_{1} = k \mid X_{1} + X_{2} = n)$, in fact I don't know how to interpret or calculate $E(X = k)$ if $X\sim Geom(p)$. I thought about just multiplying $k\cdot P(X=k)$ but I can't tell if that is correct, what does that even mean?

Comment: The notation doesn't seem to make sense. $X=k$ is not a random variable, it's an event, so it doesn't have an expected value. Maybe it's just a typo on the assignment and instead of $E[X=k]$ it's supposed to just say $E[X]$?

Comment: @JakeWestfall I think maybe it is a typo, in fact I posted the question here because maybe it's an interpretation that I don't know about so I didn't want to dismiss it as a typo right away...

Comment: So you do understand $E(X)$ if $X \sim Geom(p)$?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus yeah, it's the expected number of failures before a success or trials up to the first success, right?

Comment: It is unclear to me to which extend you do not understand the assignement. Are you puzzled about the typo, do you not know what an expected value is, do you not know how to compute an expected value, etc... At which point do you not understand the assignment? Is the geometric distribution relevant to the question? Are there other distributions for whch you are able to compute $E(X)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An expression like $E[X=k]$ doesn't have any commonly understood meaning, as far as I'm aware.

$X=k$ is not a random variable, it's an event. So it doesn't have an expected value.

This is probably a typo on your assignment and instead of $E[X=k]$ it's supposed to just say $E[X]$.

Comment: Thanks, given that my question turned out to be a typo instead of a real statistics question, should I delete it?

Comment: @RodrigoMeireles That's generally frowned upon, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question. IMO I'd say to leave it up because it's possible there is at least someone out there in the future who could benefit from reading it (maybe they come across a similar typo)